# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge

Tags: node.js, react-native

Using just the default code from `react-native init AwesomeProject`, when I run the app I get the 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge (line 1 in the generated bundle)'.

And, when I 'Reload JS', the app just has the white background rather than any 'hello world' views. I haven't touched any of the code from the init.

Any ideas how to resolve the error?

Screenshot (click to view full size):
[image]

Using:

- Ubuntu 15.10, 64-bit
- Node.js v5.3.0
- reactive-native v0.1.7
- Nexus 5X, API 6.0.1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I generally see this when the packager hasn't started. Ensure that is running by running react-native start

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same ReferenceError.

Comment: Hit the back button, hit menu, select dev settings. Select the bottom option (something about dev server) enter your computers ip with port 8081 (eg 192.168.1.30:8081) then hit ok, then back and then hit the reload button again

Comment: Works! Thank you very much! I'm glad shaking the app worked to open that menu and `ifconfig` worked to get the IPv4 address. And, the error page with the reload button disappeared after going to the menu, so another `react-native run-android` worked to reload.

Comment: On my android phone (an LG something) I hit the back button, then hit menu, then clicked on the text that reads, "DEBUGGING Debug server host & port for dev.  Debug server host & port for downloading JS bundle or communicating with JS debugger. ...." Then I entered my computers IP 192.168.1.113:8081.  Thank you rmevans9 for your answer.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am getting ERROR: can't find variable __fbbatchedbridge (<unknown file>: 1). Server is running and in developer settings IP & Port are also correct... what is going wrong here, working on React Native Android ???

Comment: Interestingly, the command is missing in ["getting started" guide from Facebook for React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and following instructions step-by-step you get this error page.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue while using Visual Studio Android Emulator. When the red screen shows up type in the command line

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

This will trigger the shake event and launch the dev menu

[image: Developer menu]

Then hit Dev Settings > Debug server host & port for device and enter `<your ip adress>:8081`. If for some reason you cannot type in the field you can trigger the text action in the command line by using

```
adb shell input text <your ip adress>:8081
```

Answer (score 5):

i solved it using this command

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you rmevans9 and Anonsage for your answers!

I am using `HTC One` on Ubuntu and there is no menu option, anyway this is the summary of the answers that worked for me:

1. Create the project

   `$ react-native init MyProject
   $ cd MyProject/`
2. In first console tab run and leave it running as you develop (`react-native start` alternative):
   `$ npm start`
3. In second console tab compile and install the project (connect the device to the USB if you want):
   `$ react-native run-android`
4. Fix `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge`:

   - Find you local ip address by executing `ifconfig` on Linux/Mac, for example:
     `inet addr:192.168.0.3`
   - Shake the device to see menu options while app is running (if you don't have "Menu" button)
   - Go to `Dev Settings` -> `Debug server host & port for device` in `Debugging` section and copy your local ip address with the specific port:
     `192.168.0.3:8081` (the port can be viewed when running `npm start` from the first tab)
     then go/press `Back`
   - Shake the device to see menu options again and press `Enable Live Reload` (to see changes live when editing)
   - Shake the device to see menu options again and press `Reload JS`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me according to documentation

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content

Using adb reverse 
Note that this option is available on devices running android 5.0+ (API 21).

Have your device connected via USB with debugging enabled (see paragraph above on how to enable USB debugging on your device).

1. Run **adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081**

You can use Reload JS and other development options with no extra configuration

2. Then Run **react-native run-android** which will automatically start dev server on 8081 port on your dev machine if not already running.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when I had specified different react native versions in my `packages.json` and my `build.gradle` file. Making sure they matched, running npm update, and rebuilding from android studio fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

As I followed all the steps mentioned in other answers, I could not resolve the issue.

In my case the `firewall` was blocking the packets coming from android.

Answer (score 0):

Also If you have submitted your app for the iTunes store, also make sure that your jsCodeLocation is back to the localhost, as shown bellow:

```
  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];

  /**
   * OPTION 2
   * Load from pre-bundled file on disk. The static bundle is automatically
   * generated by "Bundle React Native code and images" build step.
   */

   //jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```